# Undefined reference to LONG_PTR , Digital Mars C++ compiler problem

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-construction

I am using the Win Api. My program uses `LONG_PTR`. It compiles fine with both MinGW and Borland C++ Compiler. But when I try to compile it using the Digital Mars C++ Compiler it gives an error `undefined reference to LONG_PTR`. Do I have to link extra libraries for DMC, or does the DMC not support WinApu fully, or is LONG_PTR defined by some other name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the Windows headers simply don't have a correct `#ifdef` for that compiler. MSDN lists the types of all Windows API types, so it should be easy for you to look it up and provide the correct type.

Comment: I think it's more likely that DMC is shipping with some customised windows header files. Looking at the latest SDK header files, I think LONG_PTR will be declared no matter what.

Comment: The DMC compiler is unique in it's way. In my experience it has its good sides and bad ones. One good point is, although the size of a simple program executable is 36.5 kb, the size of a big program using only the *c-with-classes* type of c++ is also very close to 36.5 kb! and it stubbornly stays that way until you use templates or STL containers or something. Talk about a stream lined compiler. Or is this a bad point?